# How to use absolute values in Mozart?

Tags: oz, mozart

I'm trying to get an absolute value of expression `Z=:X-Y` but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
declare PSO
proc {PSO W}
   X Y Z W
in
   X=5
   Y=2

   Z=:Y-X
   W=:Abs(Z)

   W=w(w:W)
   {FD.distribute ff W}
end
{ExploreOne PSO}
```

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some things:
In the first line you can omit `PSO`, as you are declaring it writing its body. I can't understand your code at all, but Abs is a function, so you have to write `W = {Abs Z}` to obtain the absolute value of `Z` in `W`. Now it compiles, but it's not clear to me what your goal is. Hope it helped.